# How to create an Amazon VPC using AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scalability, vpc, aws-cloudformation

I am currently using [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) for my application. Right now I am able to auto scale the instances. Now, I want to put every thing on an [Amazon VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). Can we create a VPC using CloudFormation? And how can we manage the Elastic IP address via CloudFormation, when we have an ELB in the template? I have found a VPC related example on [AWS CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/), but it only provisions resources into an existing VPC and doesn't create a new one in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's supported now: see [AWS CloudFormation Support for Creating VPC Resources](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/04/25/aws-cloudformation-support-for-creating-vpc-resources/) for details.

Answer (score 5):

### Update

As [pointed out by Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10326412/45773) already (+1), AWS has just announced [AWS CloudFormation Support for Creating VPC Resources](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1449) as of April 25, 2012, covering the missing piece of their initial VPC support:

> We are excited to announce that AWS CloudFormation now supports the
>   creation of Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) resources. [...]
>
> Now, you can create new Virtual Private Clouds (VPC), subnets,
>   gateways, network ACLs, routes and route tables using CloudFormation
>   templates. [...]
>
> [...] A CloudFormation can now fully represent your VPC configuration
>   along with all the resources needed to run your application in the
>   VPC.

See Jeff Barr's introductory post [AWS CloudFormation Can Now Create Virtual Private Clouds](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/aws-cloudformation-can-now-create-virtual-private-clouds.html) for more details and examples. In particular, the [AWS CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) feature *two new sample templates [...] to get you started* as well:

- [VPC with a single EC2 Instance](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/vpc_single_instance_in_subnet.template) - *Sample template showing how to create a VPC and add an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP address and a security group.*
- [VPC with public and private subnets, an Elastic load Balancer, and an EC2 instance](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/vpc_multiple_subnets.template) - *Sample template showing how to create a VPC with multiple subnets. The first subnet is public and contains the load balancer, the second subnet is private and contains an EC2 instance behind the load balancer.*

---

### Initial Answer

I don't think creating an [Amazon VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) with [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) is already supported.

While AWS has just announced [AWS CloudFormation Support For VPC](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1348) as of February 12, 2012 indeed, this covers existing resource types only:

> All resource types such as Amazon EC2 instances, security groups and
>   Elastic IP addresses, Elastic Load Balancers, Auto Scaling Groups and
>   Amazon RDS Database instances can now be deployed into any existing
>   Amazon VPC using CloudFormation templates. The templates allow you to
>   run multi-tier web applications and corporate applications in a
>   private network. With Amazon VPC and CloudFormation, you can easily
>   control which resources you want to expose publicly and which ones
>   should be private.

Amazon VPC is notably absent from this list, which matches the fact that it isn't listed in the supported [AWS Resource Types Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) either.